# RabbitMq error RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable

Tags: asp.net, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I get this error when trying to execute a POST method via swagger UI.
[Swagger UI error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y58pO.png)

For context I am trying to make simple RabbitMq application.

Full error code:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)
 ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TcpClientAdapter.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.TaskExtensions.TimeoutAfter(Task task, TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectOrFail(ITcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectUsingAddressFamily(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan timeout, AddressFamily family)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.ConnectUsingIPv4(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan timeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.IProtocolExtensions.CreateFrameHandler(IProtocol protocol, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, ArrayPool`1 pool, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
   at FormulaAirline.API.Services.MessageProducer.SendingMessage[T](T message) in C:\Users\nlkaral\OneDrive - Consafe Logistics\Documents\Work\Sender\FormulaAirline.API\Services\MessageProducer.cs:line 23
   at FormulaAirline.API.Controllers.BookingsController.CreatingBooking(Booking newBooking) in C:\Users\nlkaral\OneDrive - Consafe Logistics\Documents\Work\Sender\FormulaAirline.API\Controllers\BookingsController.cs:line 31
   at lambda_method2(Closure, Object, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Here is code when connecting:

```
namespace FormulaAirline.API.Services
{
    public class MessageProducer : IMessageProducer
    { 
        public void SendingMessage<T>(T message)
        {
            // ip 
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            { 
                HostName = "", // docker IP adres left empty only in this example 
                UserName = "user",
                Password = "mypass",
                VirtualHost = "/",
                DispatchConsumersAsync = false,
                ConsumerDispatchConcurrency = 1

            };

            IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
            using var channel = conn.CreateModel();

            channel.QueueDeclare("bookings", durable: true, exclusive: true);

            var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(message);
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

            channel.BasicPublish("", "bookings", body: body);
        }
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
using FormulaAirline.API.Models;
using FormulaAirline.API.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FormulaAirline.API.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class BookingsController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    private readonly IMessageProducer _messageProducer;
    // In-Memory db
    public static readonly List<Booking> _bookings = new();

    public BookingsController(
        IMessageProducer messageProducer,
        ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _messageProducer = messageProducer;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreatingBooking(Booking newBooking)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

        _bookings.Add(newBooking);

        _messageProducer.SendingMessage<Booking>(newBooking);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The model:

```
namespace FormulaAirline.API.Models
{
    public class Booking
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string PassengerName { get; set; } = "";
        public string PassengerNb { get; set; } = "";    
        public string From { get; set; } = "";
        public string To { get; set; } = "";
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I do have a docker running, here is docker-compose.yaml I use:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    image: rabbitmq:3.12-management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass

    ports:
      # RabbitMq instance
      - '5672:5672'
      # Web interface
      - '15672:15672'
```

The issue is even if I dont run my docker it gives the same error, I also have checked the ip adress of the docker and checked if there was even a port open on 5672 and there is, I have also tried alot of solutions I found on stackoverflow but all of them didn't work, am I missing anything over the head?

I tried to connect to RabbitMq and Post a method to the Docker, and I expect that I can see the Post data appearing in the RabbitMq UI.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chkOC.png)